# How do I put JPA annotations on delegated properties in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, spring-data-jpa, annotations, delegates, eclipselink

So let's say I have a JPA entity like

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "plasmid_reference")
class PlasmidReference {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    var id: Int? = null

    @Column(name = "project_id")
    var projectId: Int? = null

    @Column(name = "plasmid_id")
    var plasmidId: Int? = null
}
```

Now, I *know* that for each and every entry in the `plasmid_reference` join table *none* of these properties will be nullable. (In fact, the database enforces this.)

How can I tell Kotlin?

A naive approach would be to try with `lateinit`...

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "plasmid_reference")
class PlasmidReference {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    lateinit var id: Int

    @Column(name = "project_id")
    lateinit var projectId: Int

    @Column(name = "plasmid_id")
    lateinit var plasmidId: Int
}
```

This does not even compile.

> 'lateinit' modifier is not allowed on properties of primitive types

Fine, let's go with the suggested solution and convert to using delegates.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "plasmid_reference")
class PlasmidReference {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    var id by notNull<Int>()

    @Column(name = "project_id")
    var projectId by notNull<Int>()

    @Column(name = "plasmid_id")
    var plasmidId by notNull<Int>()
}
```

This still does not compile because

> This annotation is not applicable to target 'member property with delegate'

ok ... that sounds like a kotlin thing and in Java, I would toss the annotation on a field, so maybe ...

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "plasmid_reference")
class PlasmidReference {

    @field:Id
    @field:GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    var id by notNull<Int>()

    @field:Column(name = "project_id")
    var projectId by notNull<Int>()

    @field:Column(name = "plasmid_id")
    var plasmidId by notNull<Int>()
}
```

No, it turns out, not really. Still does not compile because

> '@field:' annotations could be applied only to properties with backing fields

Fine, so let's annotate "the field storing the delegate instance for a delegated property" (cf. https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/annotations.html#annotation-use-site-targets )

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "plasmid_reference")
class PlasmidReference {

    @delegate:Id
    @delegate:GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    var id by notNull<Int>()

    @delegate:Column(name = "project_id")
    var projectId by notNull<Int>()

    @delegate:Column(name = "plasmid_id")
    var plasmidId by notNull<Int>()
}
```

This DOES compile but will throw a runtime exception because

```
The attribute [plasmidId] is not present in the managed type [EntityTypeImpl@960932033:PlasmidReference 
[ javaType: class com.[...].PlasmidReference descriptor: RelationalDescriptor(com.[...].PlasmidReference --> [DatabaseTable(plasmid_reference)]), mappings: 3]].
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metamodel.ManagedTypeImpl.getAttribute(ManagedTypeImpl.java:151)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.QueryUtils.toExpressionRecursively(QueryUtils.java:635)
```

Aaaaaand I'm out of ideas.

How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Moving it to the constructor definition should do the trick

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "plasmid_reference")
class PlasmidReference(
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    var id: Int? = null,
    @Column(name = "project_id")
    var projectId: Int,
    @Column(name = "plasmid_id")
    var plasmidId: Int
)
```

Comment: Nope, afraid that doesn't work: "org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DescriptorException
Exception Description: The instance creation method [com.[...].PlasmidReference.<Default Constructor>], with no parameters, does not exist, or is not accessible."

Comment: The exception says there is no no-arg constructor in your class. Hibernate needs no-arg constructor to work. It is Java framework so when we want to use it with kotlin we need to use some plugins... see https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/compiler-plugins.html

Comment: DUH, I thought these were already active since ages ago, but we only had `kotlin-noarg` instead of `kotlin-jpa`. -.- Thank you!